# Ошибка Access denied for user 'maks12345'@'localhost' to database 'databasewp'

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Хочу перенести сайт WordPress на другой домен. Экспортировал базу данных WordPress в phpMyAdmin, изменил домен и имя базы данных, хочу импортировать базу данных и появляется ошибка SQL-запрос:

База данных: `databasewp`

```
CREATE DATABASE  databasewp DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Ответ MySQL: Документация

> Access denied for user 'maks12345'@'localhost' to database 'databasewp'

Что делать?

Comment: Может такого юзера нету.

Answer (score 1):

> Что делать?

1. Забыть что уже наделал.
2. Создать базу данных средствами хостинга, а переносить сайт с пом плагинов миграции. Напр. https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Answer (score 0):

Присоединюсь к ответу SeVlad. 
Для переноса использую данный плагин - https://wordpress.org/plugins/darwin-backup/